# PDF FILE ORIENTATION detection

Tags: python, html, pdf, web-applications

I need a help to detect a orientation of a PDF file (Portrait or Landscape) by using Python. anyone has an idea?

I have been trying different libs but not successful yet.

Comment: I am okay to detect only the first page!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each page can be in a different orientation, but you can use [PyPDF](https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/) to detect the page size of the first page and determine the orientation accordingly:

```
from PyPDF2  import PdfFileReader

pdf = PdfFileReader(file('example.pdf'))
page = pdf.getPage(0).mediaBox
if page.getUpperRight_x() - page.getUpperLeft_x() > page.getUpperRight_y() - page.getLowerRight_y():
    print('Landscape')
else:
    print('Portrait')
```

Comment: Good! tnx :) also I can crop the page with this Mediabox

Comment: another challenging issue is that, how can we understand the pdf file is A4,A3 or other sizes. the mediaBox output is based on the Pixel and I tried to convert it to inches but it is not consistent with different sets of A4 size pages.

Comment: Page boxes in PDF do not use pixels but points. PDF files *always* are 72 points for an inch. If you want to check whether you have an A4, take for example the width of the mediabox / 72 * 2.54. That gives you the width in cm.

Comment: This answer ignores the effects of the page **Rotate** entry,  doesn't it?

Comment: @mkl yes, the rotation is not taken into account

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to calculate the size

```
from fpdf import FPDF
pdf = PdfReader('example.pdf')
page = pdf.getPage(1)
if page.MediaBox[3] > page.MediaBox[4]:
    print('P')
else:
    print('L')
```

Comment: This ignores quite a number of relevant details mentioned in comments to the accepted answer.